# com.ximpleware.extended.XMLBuffer.getBytes() always returns null

Tags: java, xml, vtd-xml

`com.ximpleware.extended.XMLBuffer.getBytes()` always returns `null`. 
What is the best way to modify xml using VTD-XML Huge?

Comment: You should tell more about your program. Include more of the source code.

Comment: How big is your xml? VTD-XML standard edition has the XMLModifier method... you don't need to use VTD-XML extended.

Comment: My xml is 1.6 GB and it will be bigger that that also as it is retrieved from another server. Theoretically there is no upper limit of xml size. I have to use namespace aware processing.

Answer (score 0):

For extended vtd-xml that method is supposed to return NULL.. You can not expect it to behave the same way as in standard vtd-xml... you can get a segment of bytes using some other methods

such as `writeToFileOutputStream`

Comment: Using writeToFileOutputStream impact performance and defeats the purpose of using VTD-XML. Is there any possibility to have some overloaded methods which return byte arrays in chunks?

Comment: My xml is 1.6 GB and I should be able to process even bigger ones. I was evaluating VTD-XML for better execution speed + less memory usage. I am sure 1.6GB file operation will be definitely slow.

Comment: I have managed  it with writeToFileOutputStream and after that by processing generated xml file with SAX.